# Why does extending the std namespace with a find_first_or_default function stop template deduction from working

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, std

The following function fails to compile (ISO C++ 17 Standard, Visual Studio 2019)

```
namespace std
{
    // Find the first item which matches the predicate. Returns a default constructed item (probably nullptr) on failure.
    template <class Container, typename Predicate, typename T = typename std::iterator_traits<Container::iterator>::value_type>
    T find_first_or_default(const Container& container, Predicate predicate, T defaultVal = T()) 
    {
        auto it = std::find_if(container.begin(), container.end(), predicate);
        if (it == container.end())
            return defaultVal;
        return *it;
    }
};

void Test()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1,2,3 };
    int i = std::find_first_or_default(vec, [](int val) {return val % 2 == 0; });
}
```

If I change the namespace to anything other than 'std' it DOES compile.
I assume something else inside the std namespace is making the template deduction fail.

Here are the errors:

```
Error   C2783   'T std::find_first_or_default(const Container &,Predicate,T)': could not deduce template argument for 'T'   
Error   C2672   'std::find_first_or_default': no matching overloaded function found
```

Comment: You are not allowed to add anything to namespace `std` (with very few exceptions). Compiler can do anything with such code.

Comment: Please be more specific than "fails to compile".

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: `typename std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::value_type` with this modification it compiles just fine outside the `namespace std`

Comment: Brilliant yes, thanks @pptaszni. The addition of an extra 'typename' fixes the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are not permitted to add any addition symbols to the `std` namespace, only specialize some classes when explicitly allowed.
Your program is ill-formed, however that's not that reason why it fails to compile.

In:

```cpp
typename T = typename std::iterator_traits<Container::iterator>::value_type
```

`::iterator` is dependent on the `Container` template parameter, so it would be interpreted as a static data member unless you disambiguate. Substitution would fail then, `T` could not be deduced, and you are unable to call the function then. To solve this, use the `typename` disambiguator:

```cpp
typename T = typename std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::value_type
```

If you're writing code like this a lot, it might also make sense to define a convenience alias similar to `std::ranges::range_value_t`:

```cpp
// note 1: we are not guaranteed to have a T::iterator alias, e.g. when T is an array
template <typename T>
using range_iter_t = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>()));

template <typename T>
using range_value_t = typename std::iterator_traits<range_iter_t<T>>::value_type;

// used like:

// note 2: conventional name is 'Range', not 'Container'
//         not every range is a container
template <class Range, typename Predicate, typename T = range_value_t<Range>>
// note 3: use perfect forwarding for r and and predicate because of one-time use
//         in the algorithm. std::ranges::find_if also takes Range&&
T find_first_or_default(Range&& r, Predicate&& predicate, T defaultVal = T()) 
{
    // note 4: avoid calling end() twice, end() isn't always trivial    
    // note 5: use std::begin/std::end to make this function work with C-style arrays
    auto end = std::end(r);
    // note 6: perfectly forward the predicate, don't just copy
    auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(r), end, std::forward<Predicate>(predicate));
    if (it == end)
        return defaultVal;
    return *it;
}
// note 7: it would also make sense to have a second overload which takes two
//         iterators, not just a function that takes a range
```

Comment: Great (and thorough) post, thank you very much. I will implement those changes.